# A "keyboard emulator" to input passwords from my phone into a computer

Tags: keyboards

I have a collection of many username / password combinations which I have to type frequently. If it's on my own computer, I will open my password app and paste it.

But if it's on a computer I don't own and can't install any software, I need to have a safe, airtight way of transferring this information, but still have it be straightforward and universal.

What would be ideal for me is some sort of bluetooth USB device that emulates a keyboard, I'd pair it with my phone and use it to input passwords - to the computer it would look like a regular keyboard is being used.

Is there such a thing?

Comment: I've found this: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=remote.hid.keyboard.client which requires a rooted Android phone

Comment: I'm also looking into using a Raspberry Pi Zero to emulate a HID keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

While I've not used it personally, and its not BT based, the [mooltipass](https://www.themooltipass.com) is a standalone device designed for this very task.

It'll store passwords (selectable through a scrollwheel, and shown on a screen), and input it via usb. Its *really* secure (using a smartcard for extra security), reasonably idiotproof though I have no idea how it scales to lots of passwords